# How to test if a variable is defined at all in Bash prior to version 4.2 with the nounset shell option?

Tags: bash, test

For Bash versions prior to "GNU bash, Version 4.2" are there any equivalent alternatives for the `-v` option of the `test` command? For example:

```
shopt -os nounset
test -v foobar && echo foo || echo bar
# Output: bar
foobar=
test -v foobar && echo foo || echo bar
# Output: foo
```

Comment: `-v` isn't an option to `test`, but an operator for conditional expressions.

Comment: @Tim It is three things, beside being a token, an string and part of a line: An `option` to a command `test -v`, an `operator` to a `conditional expression` and a `unary test primary` for `[ ]`. Don't mix English language with shell definitions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Portable to all POSIX shells:

```
if [ -n "${foobar+1}" ]; then
  echo "foobar is defined"
else
  echo "foobar is not defined"
fi
```

Make that `${foobar:+1}` if you want to treat `foobar` the same way whether it is empty or not defined. You can also use `${foobar-}` to get an empty string when `foobar` is undefined and the value of `foobar` otherwise (or put any other default value after the `-`).

In ksh, if `foobar` is declared but not defined, as in `typeset -a foobar`, then `${foobar+1}` expands to the empty string.

Zsh doesn't have variables that are declared but not set: `typeset -a foobar` creates an empty array.

In bash, arrays behave in a different and surprising way. `${a+1}` only expands to `1` if `a` is a non-empty array, e.g.

```
typeset -a a; echo ${a+1}    # prints nothing
e=(); echo ${e+1}            # prints nothing!
f=(''); echo ${f+1}          # prints 1
```

The same principle applies to associative arrays: array variables are treated as defined if they have a non-empty set of indices.

A different, bash-specific way of testing whether a variable of any type has been defined is to check whether it's listed in `${!PREFIX*}`. This reports empty arrays as defined, unlike `${foobar+1}`, but reports declared-but-unassigned variables (`unset foobar; typeset -a foobar`) as undefined.

```
case " ${!foobar*} " in
  *" foobar "*) echo "foobar is defined";;
  *) echo "foobar is not defined";;
esac
```

This is equivalent to [testing the return value of `typeset -p foobar` or `declare -p foobar`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56838), except that `typeset -p foobar` fails on declared-but-unassigned variables.

In bash, like in ksh, `set -o nounset; typeset -a foobar; echo $foobar` triggers an error in the attempt to expand the undefined variable `foobar`. Unlike in ksh, `set -o nounset; foobar=(); echo $foobar` (or `echo "${foobar[@]}"`) also triggers an error.

Note that in all situations described here, `${foobar+1}` expands to the empty string if and only if `$foobar` would cause an error under `set -o nounset`.

Comment: What about arrays? In Bash version "GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)" `echo "${foobar:+1}"` doesn't print `1` if `declare -a foobar` was previously issued and thus `foobar` is an indexed array. `declare -p foobar` correctly reports `declare -a foobar='()'`. Does `"${foobar:+1}"` only work for non-array variables?

Comment: @TimFriske `${foobar+1}` (without the `:`, I inverted two examples in my original answer) is correct for arrays in bash if your definition of “defined” is “would `$foobar` work under `set -o nounset`”. If your definition is different, bash is a bit weird. See my updated answer.

Comment: Regarding the topic "In bash, arrays behave in a different and surprising way." the behavior can be explained from the bash(1) manpages, section "Arrays". It states that "Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.". Thus if neither a `0` index nor a key is defined as it is true for `a=()`, `${a+1}` correctly returns nothing.

Comment: @TimFriske I know that the bash implementation conforms to its documentation. But treating an empty array like an undefined variable is really strange design.

Comment: I prefer the result from: [How to check if a variable is set in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/108350) -->  **[The Right Way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/108350)**  ... I strikes a chord with how I thing this *ought* to work.  Dare I say, Windows has a **`defined`** operator.   `Test` _could_ DO that; it can't be difficult (_um_ ....)

Comment: @will My first command is the same as the “Right Way”, we just inverted the test (if set vs if unset). The rest of my answer is a digression on bash arrays. The `test` command doesn't do that because it was historically implemented as a separate command (and it still is, but most if not all modern and even not-so-modern shells also have it built in).

Answer (score 7):

To sum up with Gilles' answer I made up my following rules:

1. Use `[[ -v foobar ]]` for variables in Bash version >= 4.2.
2. Use `declare -p foobar &>/dev/null` for array variables in Bash version < 4.2.
3. Use `(( ${foo[0]+1} ))` or `(( ${bar[foo]+1} ))` for subscripts of indexed (`-a`) and keyed (`-A`) arrays (`declare`), respectively. Options 1 and 2 don't work here.

Answer (score 3):

I use the same technique for all variables in bash, and it works, e.g.:

```
[ ${foobar} ] && echo "foobar is set" || echo "foobar is unset"
```

outputs:

```
foobar is unset
```

whilst

```
foobar=( "val" "val2" )
[ ${foobar} ] && echo "foobar is set" || echo "foobar is unset"
```

outputs:

```
foobar is set
```

Comment: Had to remove [@] if array has more than one value.

Comment: This works great, so long as you want to test whether it has a value, not whether it's been defined. I.e., `foobar=""` will then report that `foobar is unset`. No wait, I take that back. Really only tests if first element is empty or not, so it seems to be only a good idea if you know the variable is NOT an array, and you only care about emptiness, not definedness.

Comment: only works if your scripts are running with undefined variables allowed (no set -u)