# How to assign a zero-length, non-null string

Tags: bash, variable, null

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280430/are-the-null-string-and-the-same-string), amongst many other things I've read, my understanding is that `a=''` makes `a` both null and zero-length.  But, then, how does one create a zero-length, non-null string?  Or, is there no such thing?  To the extent this is shell-dependent, I'm working in bash.

Comment: if it's zero-length, how could it be non-null?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It sounds like your answer to the second half of my question, "Or, is there no such thing?", is "yes".

Comment: I just wasn't sure if you intended something else, like "set" vs "unset", because it sounded like a contradiction to me.

Comment: It seems to me that the answers to the question you linked to would answer this one; do you agree, or what part is left over? e.g. `a null string in that context is a string of length 0 containing no byte at all`

Comment: Frankly, just being able to be certain whether, in the context of a set variable,  "zero-length", "empty", and "null" are the same thing is what I've been struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A null string" *means* "a zero length (empty) string".  See e.g. [the POSIX definition of "null string"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_250).  This means that there is no such thing as a non-null zero length string.

However, there *is* such a thing as an *unset* variable.

```
var=''
unset uvar
```

There's now a difference between `var` and `uvar` after running the above code.  For example, `${var-hello}` would expand to the empty string since `var` is set, while `${uvar-hello}` would expand to `hello` since `uvar` is unset.  Likewise, `${var+hello}` would expand to `hello` since `var` is set, and `${uvar+hello}` would expand to an empty string since `uvar` is unset (see [standard parameter expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02))

In `bash`, you can also use the `-v` test to test whether a variable is set or not:

```
if [ -v variable ]; then
    echo variable is set
fi
```

Again, a variable being "set but empty" is different from a variable being "unset".  A string (contents of a variable) can't be null and at the same have non-zero length.

In other languages, an array of characters may contain nul bytes (`\0`), which means that you may have an array starting off with a nul byte, and then containing some text after that (terminated with another nul byte).  When that is interpreted as a *string*, that string would have zero length, but the contents of the array would not be empty.

Most shells (apart from `zsh`) does not allow nul bytes in variables though.

Comment: You switch from "null" to "nul", are they different?  Most shells don't allow nul(l) bytes **anywhere** in variables, or just at the start?

Comment: @TTT "nul byte" means a `\0` character. "Null" means "empty". They are distinct. Most shells don't allow nul bytes anywhere in variables (as it is what _terminates the internal representation of a string_).