# Is this a correct way to test if a parameter is declared?

Tags: bash

Here is an example from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56846/674

> A different, bash-specific way of testing whether a variable of any type has been declared is to check whether it's listed in `${!PREFIX*}`:
>
> ```
> case " ${!foobar*} " in
>   *" foobar "*) echo "foobar is declared";;
>   *) echo "foobar is not declared";;
> esac
> ```

1. If I am correct, to make a parameter not declared, we use `unset` builtin. The `unset` case works like the quote said,

   ```
   $ unset foobar
   $ case " ${!foobar*} " in
   >   *" foobar "*) echo "foobar is declared";;
   >   *) echo "foobar is not declared";;
   > esac
   foobar is not declared
   ```

   but the `declare`d case
   doesn't:

   ```
   $ unset foobar
   $ declare foobar
   $ case " ${!foobar*} " in
   >   *" foobar "*) echo "foobar is declared";;
   >   *) echo "foobar is not declared";;
   > esac
   foobar is not declared
   ```

   Is this a correct way to test if a parameter is declared?
2. Also in `" ${!foobar*} "`, why are there spaces before and after the
   parameter expansion? Does it work when `foobar` is an array or dictinary and when it is a variable but not an array or dictionary?

Comment: Related: [How do I check if a variable exists in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246703)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks like you'd have to declare the variable with a value (can be null):

   ```
   unset foobar; declare foobar=
   ```

   The case statement will produce "foobar is declared".
2. you use quotes and spaces so the `*" foobar "*` can detect the specific variable name out of the *list* of varnames returned by `${!foobar*}`:

   ```
   $ unset foobar; foobarbaz=1; foobarquz=2
   $ echo " ${!foobar*} "
    foobarbaz foobarquz
   ```

   The case statement will produce "foobar is not declared".

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused. What does `*" foobar "*` expand to? Does `*` match any string, so `foobarbaz` should be in `*" foobar "*`?

Comment: In that context, it's a **pattern** where `*` will match zero or more of any character. We are checking if the string `" foobar "` is *contained* in the string `" ${!foobar*} "`